# Zend Download File Chrome

Tags: file, zend-framework, google-chrome, layout, download

When I use the code below to download a file it works fine in IE, Firefox, but with Chrome you can see that the layout and view is sent back to the browser in the console.The status is set to cancel and the entire line is highlighted in red. The file is downloaded OK.

After the exit; there are various header opions I have tried, but to no avail

```
if ($request->isPost()) {

    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();


$file_fullpath = "C:/eclipse-php/workspace/Dartfire/uploads/data/logo.jpg";

$mtype = '';
// magic_mime module installed?
if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
    $mtype = mime_content_type($file_fullpath);
}
// fileinfo module installed?
else if (function_exists('finfo_file')) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME); // return mime type
    $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $file_fullpath);
    finfo_close($finfo); 
}

$size = filesize($file_fullpath);

header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="logo.jpg"');
readfile($file_fullpath);

exit; 


//header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

        /*
$this->getResponse()
    ->setHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer', true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Type', $mtype, true) // change to application/pdf
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename={$document->getFilename()}", true)
        ->setHeader('Content-length', $size, true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true)
        ->setHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
        ->setHeader('Cache-control', 'private')
    ->appendBody(readfile($file_fullpath));
        //->sendHeaders();

//$this->getResponse()->sendResponse(); 
//Zend_Wildfire_Channel_HttpHeaders::getInstance()->flush();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to place any `header()` calls before any output is sent to the browser. So, in your case this would need to be done before the `readline()` call.

Comment: The header calls after the readFILE() are all commented out - they are just an indication of things I have tried.

Comment: understand that but when you tried them out, did you in fact place the readfile() part at the very end?